# Insert into an SQL database in PHP using incremental Dates and Days

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am looking to insert data into an SQL database that has these columns.

`id, date, day, Month, Projection, RecommendedStaff, StaffWages, TotalWages, Actual`

I found the insert into statement which works when using it as a query to enter a constant, however I can't find the syntax for incrementing these values and for it to work successfully. The ID is auto-incremental therefore there is no issue with this just trying to understand how to increment date and day values.

For example:

```
Date / Day / Month

2017-03-20 / Monday / March
```

**INSERT QUERY COMPLETED**

```
2017-03-21 / Tuesday / March
```

**OR WHEN MONTH CHANGES**

```
2017-04-01 / Saturday / April
```

I want to be able to increment by a certain period of days based on the current date therefore my guess would be a *while* loop with the variable as the amount of days.

My current theory of incrementing values however it doesn't insert into mySQL database:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `Test` (date) VALUES (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))";

    if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New records created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a PHP way you can achieve what you want.

```
$fDate = $date->format("Y-m-d");
$date = '2017-03-02';

$begin = new DateTime($date);
$end = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . '+ 1 year'))); // you can change + 1 year to what you need

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D'); // one day
//$interval = new DateInterval('P1W'); // one week

$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `Test` (`date`, `day`, `Month`) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $fDate, $fDay, $fMonth);
foreach ($daterange as $date) { // loop through dates
    $fDate = $date->format("Y-m-d"); // format date to the format you need
    $fDay = $date->format("l"); // (lower case L) e.g. Sunday
    $fMonth = $date->format("F"); // e.g. January

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

You can see [here](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php) how you can user strtotime() function.

**Update** After reading the question again in full ;)

I changed the loop to also give you day and month.
You can format a date to whatever you need. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for the parameters you can pass to the date function.

Comment: Thank you I understand this. So therefore to simply include the days I could just add a counter that is the index of an array that loops through?

Comment: `Error: INSERT INTO "Test" (date) VALUES ('2017-03-03')` just getting this error

Comment: My first guess would be that your column "date" is a preserved word in MySQL (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html). So are the words "day", "month". You can fix that by either escaping date like this: `date` or change the column name to be something else e.g. test_date

Comment: Thank you very much, where can I find more information about the format such as why `"l"` and `"F"` changes the day/month

Comment: You can find all formats in the parameters section here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

You can make a procedure and using that looping you can insert multiple records

As shown in below code if you want to insert 100 days records from current date,just replace that `count_1` variable `10` to `100` and it will iterate your loop for `100` times and Make `entry` for `100 days` .

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test$$
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
BEGIN
   DECLARE count_1 INT DEFAULT 0;
   WHILE count_1 < 10 DO
      /**Sql statement**/
      SET count_1 = count_1 + 1;
      INSERT INTO `Test` (date) VALUES (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL count_1 DAY));
   END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Hope this will helps.

Comment: As I am new to SQL itself, could you explain your code a little more so I can understand it?

Comment: @ParagonJenko as shown in code,we just create one procedure which contains loop for multiple entry and i had placed your INSERT statement into that loop with dynamic `count_1` variable .So it will make entry for 

`DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))`
`DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 DAY))`
...
And so on.
Hope this will helps you.